# Picking the right ExecutionContext

Tags: scala, asynchronous, future, nonblocking

I've been working on a small/medium web application, with approximately 10 endpoints. It's supposed to handle hundreds of simultaneous concurrent requests.

Because of my company policy I had to use `javax.ws.rs` for my controllers, so every controller method returns a `javax.ws.rs.core.Response`

Every controller depends on a Service, which is responsible to go to the database (DynamoDB, using the v2 non-blocking java dynamoDb sdk), obtain data from other microservices through http (Using org.asynhttpclient), and create the case class representing my response, so my controller can serialize it and return it as the body in the `javax.ws.rs.core.Response`.

Every component in my application is async and non-blocking, my services returns `Future[Either[MyAppError, CaseClassRepresentingMyResponse]]`. Then, in the controller, just at the end I Await for the future result, and create the `javax.ws.rs.core.Response`:

So my controllers looks like this:

```scala
class BarController(barService: BarService)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) {

   def getFoo(userId: BigInt, fooId: String): Response = withMetrics(Bar.ServiceName, Bar.GetFoo) {
    val fooResponse = for {
      _     <- EitherT(validateUserIdAndFooId(userId, fooId))
      foo   <- EitherT(barServiceService.getFoo(userId, fooId))
    } yield foo

    Await.result(fooResponse.value, 10 seconds) match {
      case Success(Right(r)) => buildOkResponse(r)
      case Success(Left(NotFound)) => HttpResponses.notFound
      (.... a bunch of other cases ......) 
    }
  }
}
```

(I am using cats EitherT to handle `Future[Either[E, A]]`.)

Every component in my app receives an implicit `ExecutionContext`, and returns a `Future[Either[E,A]]`.

Now, I've just finished all the coding and tests, and I need to provide a proper `ExecutionContext` in my configuration.

Would `ExecutionContext.global` be enough? Considering my code never blocks (since I am using DynamoDb non-blocking sdk and org.asynchttpclient), or should I create a different ExecutionContext? Maybe a from a FixedThreadPool? or a ForkJoinPool?

Comment: I guess you may just use global for now and benchmark, if you start to have problems you can try to tune it using a custom one.

Comment: `Await.result` definitely blocks, use `future.onComplete {...}` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are a great articles about that.
https://jessitron.com/2014/01/29/choosing-an-executorservice/
https://gist.github.com/djspiewak/46b543800958cf61af6efa8e072bfd5c

It looks like you have just computations.